# Electron js - How to get associated icon of a file that's being downloaded

Tags: electron

I understand that this is the way of getting a icon of a file in the drive.

```
app.getFileIcon(filePath, { size: "normal" }, (err: Error, icon: NativeImage) => {
     
});
```

How to I get the get the the icon of file that I'm downloading, say if I'm downloading a .mp3 file, I'd like to view the associated icon for mp3 files

Comment: You mean something like this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty-file-icons)?

Comment: No. Like the associated icons the system uses

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating a temporary file that has the same extension as the file being downloaded and then using [`app.getFileIcon`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetfileiconpath-options) on that file

```js
const { app } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs/promises");

const getFileIconFromExt = async (ext) => {
  const tempFile = path.join(__dirname, `temp${ext}`);
  await fs.writeFile(tempFile, ""); // create empty temp file
  const image = await app.getFileIcon(tempFile); // get file icon of temp file
  await fs.unlink(tempFile); // delete temp file
  return image;
};

// usage
async () => {
  const icon = await getFileIconFromExt(".mp3"); // file icon of .mp3 files
}
```